# How to make the CommandBar point down in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

The CommandBar expands upward when the button is pressed. How to make the CommandBar expand in the opposite direction?

[image]

Code:

```
     <CommandBar>
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Shuffle" Label="Shuffle" />
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="RepeatAll" Label="Repeat"/>
        <AppBarSeparator/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Stop" Label="Stop" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Play" Label="Play" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward"/>
        
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Now playing..." Margin="12,14"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit the `ControlTemplate` as suggested [here](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/02/forcing-the-commandbar-to-open-down/).

There is a full code example available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/blog-2017/tree/master/OpenDownCommandBar):

```
<CommandBar Style="{StaticResource OpenDownCommandBar}">
    <CommandBar.Content>
        ...
    </CommandBar.Content>
</CommandBar>
```